# Using the Socialcast API using PHP?

Tags: php, api, basic-authentication

Can someone help me understand how to use Socialcast's API with PHP?  I'd like to grab [this data](https://demo.socialcast.com/api/messages/search.xml?q=enterprise) (note: the demo username/password are emily@socialcast.com/demo) using PHP so that I can format it and display it, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

The documentation for their API is below and unfortunately they don't provide any code samples:

http://developers.socialcast.com/api-documentation/api/messages/search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a remote file by using [file_get_contents();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)  .
This commands allow you to fetch any local/remote file. You can also do this with the [fopen();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function.
But the best solution for more advanced queries would be  [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: The main problem I have is that they use basic auth, but using the username and password in the URL (i.e. ttps://emily@socialcast.com:demo@demo.socialcast.com/api/messages/search.xml?q=enterprise) worked.  I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but this is just for fun and not too big of a deal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP Curl library for achieving this. You can substitute the $this->url, userName and password values in the below script.

```
function makeCall() {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->userName . ":" . $this->password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);  
        $returnValue = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $returnValue;
}
```